# IDE in Groovy, Is that Possible?

Tags: java, groovy

I thought of creating simple IDE with the help of Groovy language, and i know that with the help of `Swingbuilder` i can design or put the layout of my IDE. Are there are other lib available in Groovy/In java for syntax checking for a specific language like that which will help in building the IDE?

My question is that possible to build an IDE with the help of groovy?(My IDE is simple, like just syntax checking, error highlighting, thats it)

Comment: And why do you need it? There are many IDE out there, including those, who understand Groovy.

Comment: @Frozen : nice question, i just want to build a tool, with groovy.. thats what iam looking for..

Comment: @frozen: not an intension to beat NetBeans! Just want to build a tool..

Comment: Don't forget to check [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org)

Comment: @Tomasz: i guess Griffon lacks documentations and books, thats the reason I'm looking in Groovy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax checking is one of the more difficult parts of building something like an IDE.  If you want to make a tool, I suggest concentrating on the editor and not worry about the syntax checking.

You could attempt to run Groovy code through the groovy compiler and report the message that comes out, but when you are typing most code won't even compile so the error will generally be some kind of "Syntax error".

If you really want to do it you should review some stuff on building compilers because that's essentially what you will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can use every java library in groovy, like awt or swing. Or you could even use the rich client platform from eclipse, Equinox.

As you already know there are some helpers in groovy like the Swingbuilder.
More about GUI's in Groovy you can find here:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/GUI+Programming+with+Groovy

I would recommend to use one of these if you don't want to get too complex